# Umbraco auto generate web.config if missing

Tags: msbuild, umbraco

We have a Umbraco website that references `Umbraco.Web.UI`,

```
<Reference Include="Umbraco.Web.UI, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\UmbracoCms.Web.8.12.2\lib\net472\Umbraco.Web.UI.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If we see the source code of `Umbraco.Web.UI`, then we see there is copy action that generates web.config from web.Template.config.

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/34e80d86e8c0b754f6b7a02e307f53cb32806bbe/src/Umbraco.Web.UI/Umbraco.Web.UI.csproj#L369

But as far as I know if I just reference `Umbraco.Web.UI.dll` then these MSBuild actions in `Umbraco.Web.UI.dll` will not run.

My question is that how come web.config is generated if I build the project and web.config is missing.

The problem is that we have removed `web.config` from the repository and we wanna to understand how this web.config is generated so that we can modify it when we deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my csproj is using,

```
<Import Project="..\packages\UmbracoCms.8.12.2\build\UmbracoCms.targets"
```

and `UmbracoCms.targets` have the below action

[image]